# Convert Yii to Yii 2.0: getRestParams()

Tags: yii, yii2, upgrade, yii2-model

How to write this line of code from Yii to Yii 2.0:

`Yii::app()->getRequest()->getRestParams()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the equivalent of

```
Yii::app()->getRequest()->getRestParams()
```

in Yii 2 is

```
Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()
```

moreover, if you would like to know the method of the request (POST, PATCH, DELETE etc.), you can use `Yii::$app->request->getMethod()`

More information about the `Request` class instance you can find [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html).

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is

```
Yii::$app->request->restParams
```

or

```
Yii::$app->getRequest()->getRestParams()
```

and you may find the following issue interesting

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/259

Answer (score 2):

you can use it this way

```
Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()
```

there are more similar methods, please check here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request

see the guide article as well https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests

Answer (score 1):

According to Yii1 it is changed like the below.

```
Yii::$app->request->bodyParams;
```

You can see here for other details also.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
 Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam()
```

[check this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html)